# List of acceptable literature for religious schools

Tags: chinuch-education, yeshiva-school, book-banning

A while back I came across an article about an organization that compiled a list of acceptable literature (I believe fiction titles) for Jewish religious schools. Does anyone know where I can find this list? Is it online somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send an e-mail to **kosherbooks@juno.com** requesting the kosher book list and they will send it to you.

Comment: Same list is available on chinuch.org - search for 'secular book list'.

Comment: It is adifferent list with much more details and choices.

Comment: http://savvima.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/4552B_a_00663_book_list_with_comments_and_cover1.pdf